# How to place Notification Authorization Request for FCM outside AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

when we want to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging, we first have to ask permission for notification to the user. from Firebase Documentation they recommend this lines of codes to be implemented in Appdelegate on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like below :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()


        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


        return true
    }
```

but if place those codes in appDelegate, the pop up alert to ask permission will show up immediately after the user open up my app.but I want to show the alert in the certain View Controller.

if I move those code to a VC, then the `application` is not available, since the `application` comes from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. and then the messagingDelegate ... I am not sure. could you please help me to rewrite those codes but if it is not in AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1):

I was testing on a iOS 10.3.3 device and it didn't register until I set the delegate of the `UNUserNotificationCenter` to `UIApplication.shared.delegate as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` implementing delegate in the `AppDelegate` as an empty delegate. But it didn't work implementing an empty delegate in the current view controller.

AppDelegate.swift:

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate { }
```

So here's the method in my view controller:

```
private func registerPushNotifications() {
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {granted, _ in
                if granted {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    }
                }
        })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

Of course you have to leave `FirebaseApp.configure()` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Later edit: You might get a warning about calling `registerForRemoteNotifications()` from the main thread, so I adjusted the code to do that.

Answer (score 0):

### Add a Class

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID
import UserNotifications

class Notifications {

    private init() { }
    static let shared = Notifications()

    func requestNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (isAuthorized, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error as Any)
                return
            } else {
                print("set up successfully")
                // Completion Code Here:
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Add to your prefered VC

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        Notifications.shared.requestNotifications()
    }
```